# jQuery click function converted in hover on full width dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, dropdown

I need modifying the jQuery code so when hovering over full width dropdown it opens instead of clicking on it, but when width is less than 798px, the dropdown must stay the way it is now, opened when clicked.

I have been trying to change .click to .hover, but without success. On this state it opens the dropdown menu when hovered, but on mouse out it closes immediately.
It would be good for someone to share a solution on this problem, because this is not my code(downloaded free) and I am not well in JavaScript programming.

Thank you,
CP

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #2581DC;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #262626;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Services</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Portfolio</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Needing mods on a script you didn't write is not enough reason to ask people to work for free. [so] is aimed at making you a better programmer, not at providing free coding services. If you are here to learn, not to get a job done, share what you tried and we'll tell you how to fix/improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps, you just neede to locate the listener and make an if to manage the screen width.

Could be prettier, if needed will be happy to provide it.

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    if ($(window).width() < 798) {
      // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
      $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
        // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    } else {
      $('nav ul li a').hover(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
        // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery

$(window).resize(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #2581DC;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* Mobile navigation */

.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #262626;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Services</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Portfolio</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's not working, I've already tried that (except enclosed in media query conditional function), also on size less than 798px it must be clicking enabled and not with hover. The menu opens fine with clicking, but the list is still opened on hover

Comment: I dont know what you want. if you can explain it clearly, ican help

Comment: When browser width is more than 798px, submenus have to be opened by hovering on them, but when the width is less or equal to 798px, submenus have to be opened by clicking on them. Also another problem is, when changing .click into .hover function, after mouse is out of the rectangle of the dropdown, the submenu immediately disappears. Hope this helps. Please accept my appologies for my bad explanation.

Comment: First lets solve the hover problem. I made a few changes and added a function to reload page when screen is resize. The problem is that the listener is made when the page is loaded and depending on the window width at that time. Once you resize it the listeners stay that way. Using this function it reloads and remake the listeners. Another way would be making both listener and every time they trigger, validate the width and do or dont do an action depending on the width. I dont really understand the second problem but this solves the original problem

Comment: @catapultedplastic i need a little more than "lost" to be able to help you

Comment: When browser is at full width, submenu opens on hover, and suddenly disappears when trying to hover over the listed items(for example in 'Services'). When width is less than 798px menu opens with a click, but submenus are opened on hover until refreshing browser on that size(<798px).

Comment: Yes thats because the hover is set on the main link as you asked. Theres no css class on the ul to keep it on display:block. I think you should look for a solution outside js. I will happily help you but on more direct questions. I will aprciate the rep you can give when i help you solve your problem. But i am starting to think you wont really give it until your page is 100% done. Please learn by doing, follow tutorials and documentation and use frameworks that will solve this kind of stuff. Ex bootstrap

Comment: Resetting after refresh to the original state is not a solution, but no problem, here is your rep+. I feel the obligation not to check this answer as solution, because it might lead someone else into wrong direction. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161369/discussion-between-gerardo-blanco-and-catapultedplastic).